# How to reuse code if I have two similar Component?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

For example I have two following Components:

```
// ItemA.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
  // a lot of attributes ...
  PartA {}
  // more attributes ...
}

// ItemB.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
  // a lot of attributes ...
  PartB {}
  // more attributes ...
}
```

In fact, the only difference between `ItemA` and `ItemB` is that `ItemA` has `PartA` while `ItemB` has `PartB`.

How could I write it so that I have to write only once what `ItemA` and `ItemB` have in common?

Comment: Move the outer item into its own file BaseItem.qml?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Good idea in this case. Thank you.